# Regex for numbers after a certain string part

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to extract numbers inside an URL with regex.

```
Example Input: http://localhost:23089/generic-url-segment-c?p=5

Expected Output : 5

Example Input: http://localhost:23089/generic-url-segment-c?p=12&sort=5

Expected Output: 12
```

First I tried to look for the numbers with a mixture of `string.replace`,`string.indexof` and `substring` but thought Regex would be easier.

So far I tried using `((p=)?=.)` but can't get the 5 only.

And also as shown in second example, this value might be a two digit value or there even might be other parameters after it. So maybe a search between `p=` and `&` is necessary but I don't know how Regex behaves in absence of parameters.

Comment: Use right to left option and then simply use \d+

Comment: If you have linked to System.Web it might be more reliable to use the following: HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(new Uri("your url here").Query)["p"]

Comment: Thanks @MartinBrown, this looks like a more solid way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below pattern. The plus matches 1 or more so you can get 1 or more digits -

```
 p=(\d+)
```

The brackets are a group so to get the value of the match within the group use

```
match.Groups[1].Value
```

Comment: What language are you using? Look at the 'group' under match info on regex101, you will see only the 5 is matched

Comment: @EgeBayrak You need to match group 1 rather than the full match.

Comment: Ok I managed to get 5 by using match.Groups[Index].Value, if you can modift your answer to include this I can accept it as correct answer

Comment: @EgeBayrak: Be aware that regex matches `5` in `group=5` or `anythingThatEndWith_p=5`

Answer (score 2):

You could use lookbehind:

```
(?<=\bp=)\d+
```

or

```
(?<=[?&]p=)\d+
```

Usage:

```
Regex.Match(str, @"(?<=[?&]p=)\d+").Value;
```

Comment: Or `(?<=\b\?p=)\d+` to be more specific => C# usage: `Regex.Match(str, @"(?<=\b\?p=)\d+").Value;` ;).

Comment: @shA.t: Thanks edited, 've added the possibility of `&`